# Take a fs path as a param in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So i want a route that can take a fs path as a parameter like this:
`GET "/test/*fs_path", FsController, :fsc`
this pattern that i used here: `*fs_path` does match fs paths however it just deletes all `/` characters from the actual `fs_path` so a request  like this: `GET /test/directory/file.json` will give `fs_path` the following value: `directoryfile.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely hard to tell what are you doing wrong without you showing the code, bus assuming you have `"/test/*fs_path"` in your router handled by `SomeController.test/2` callback, the second argument to this function (named `params`) would contain

```elixir
%{"test" => ["directory", "file.json"]}
```

and you might concatenate it back then with `Path.join/1` or something.